# Is it possible to customize Gif generation frame-rate with image package?

Tags: flutter, image, gif, frame-rate

I've managed to generate an animated GIF image from a set of images on a temporary directory on my storage, with the `image` package. But I don't if it is possible to customize the frame-rate of the generated GIF image.

This my current generation code :

```dart
void _mergeScreenshotsIntoGif({
    required int gameStepsCount,
    required String tempStorageDirPath,
    required String baseFilename,
  }) async {
    final animation = image.Animation();
    final imageDecoder = image.PngDecoder();
    for (var stepIndex = 1; stepIndex <= gameStepsCount; stepIndex++) {
      final currentFile = File(
          '$tempStorageDirPath${Platform.pathSeparator}${baseFilename}_$stepIndex.png');
      final currentImageBytes = await currentFile.readAsBytes();
      final currentImage = imageDecoder.decodeImage(currentImageBytes)!;
      animation.addFrame(currentImage);
    }
    final gifData = image.encodeGifAnimation(animation);
    if (gifData == null) {
      //TODO handle gif generation error
      return;
    }
    final destinationFile =
        File('$tempStorageDirPath${Platform.pathSeparator}$baseFilename.gif');
    await destinationFile.writeAsBytes(gifData);
  }
```

I've looked at the [documentation of the package](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/encodeGifAnimation.html), but did not manage to reach my needs.

So is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a naive implementation, but I managed to "slow" the animation. By adding the different images several times.

Replacing

```dart
animation.addFrame(currentImage);
```

with

```dart
for (var frameRepetitionIndex = 0;
   frameRepetitionIndex < 10;
   frameRepetitionIndex++) {
   animation.addFrame(currentImage);
}
```